# modify_instance_attribute() only accepts keyword arguments

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I have following task:

1.Check if the instance has a tag "Terminate_On"

If yes:

2.Check if the instance should be terminated today

If yes:

3.Remove instance termination protection if enabled
Terminate the instance

I'm stuck on part 3: don't know how to remove protection if enabled

```
response=ec.modify_instance_attribute(instance_ids,"disableApiTermination", "true" )
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
TypeError: modify_instance_attribute() only accepts keyword arguments.
```

If i modify as this one:

```
ec.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceIds=instance_ids,"disableApiTermination", "true" )
```

Then getting:

non-keyword arg after keyword arg (lambda_function.py, line 34)

```
import boto3   
import collections     
import datetime     
import time     
import sys 

ec = boto3.client('ec2', 'eu-west-1')     
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', 'eu-west-1')     
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date_after_month = datetime.now()+ relativedelta(days=7)
#print date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
today=datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')


def lambda_handler(event, context):           
    instance_ids = []
    reservations = ec.describe_instances(     
        Filters=[     
            {'Name': 'tag:Owner', 'Values': ['Unknown', 'unknown']},     
        ]     
    ).get('Reservations', []) 

    for reservation in reservations:
          instances = reservation['Instances']
          for instance in instances:
              instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])
              tags = {}
              for tag in instance['Tags']:
                tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']  
                if 'TerminateOn' in tags:  
                  if tags["TerminateOn"]==today:
                    #remove termination protection if enabled
                    ec.modify_instance_attribute(instance_ids,"disableApiTermination", "true" )
                    #terminate instance
                    ec.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=instance_ids)
                  else: 
                    print "No need for termination"
                if not 'TerminateOn' in tags:  
                     ec2.create_tags(Resources=instance_ids,Tags=[{'Key':'TerminateOn','Value':date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}])



print("Stopping instances: {}".format(','.join(instance_ids)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to boto3 `modify_instance_attribute` [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_instance_attribute), try this (not tested code):

```
ec.modify_instance_attribute(
    InstanceIds=instance_id, 
    DisableApiTermination={'Value': True})
```

Comment: `"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceId, value: ['i-07d2c5b7056bc639d'], type: <type 'list'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>"`

Comment: You are trying to pass a list as argument and the function expects a string. Use only one instance  id, not the entire list. In your case that may be `instance['InstanceId']`